# A light Linux distro compatible with VM "guest" software?

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-distributions, vmware-tools, guest-additions

Is there a light Linux distro (like PuppyLinux, Slitaz etc) but which supports "guest"/"support" software (like VMware Tools, VirtualBox Additions).

Answer (score 1):

If you take a 'minimal' Debian or CentOS installation you end up with an extremely small footprint system that you can then add things to (like a desktop environment) as you please. Both of them are compatible with the two virtualizers you listed.

Answer (score 0):

Any distribution that runs with `XFCE` or `LXCE` desktop managers will be very much light weighted and you will be able to use virtualbox and vmware with ease. I would suggest the LMDE (Linux Mint Desktop edition) which runs on the new `MATE` desktop manager which is a fork from classic gnome2. It is pretty light, and i've seen it to be very good. Or else `LUBUNTU` on lxce and `XUBUNTU` on xfce should be good for you.

Comment: All of these can install vmware tools and vb additions software? the ones i've tried, including mint failed to compile the "virtual" drivers

Comment: According to virtualbox website, virtualbox additions exists for all supported guest operating systems. Linux kernel 2.6.13 and above should perform well. Refer article http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html.